# drawing shapes one by one as time passes instead of all at once

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I want to create a line and after 2 sec break another line and so on. 
If i draw a line and pause program execution with Thread.sleep() and again draw a line within paintComponent() method then what happens is first the program stops for 2 second and then both lines are drawn simultaneously.
how to overcome this problem?

Comment: What you need is a game loop.

Comment: I know. I did these things while working with C++ Sfml library. But with swing, do i have to create JPanel object again and again within the game loop with different parameters(eg- no lines to draw as a parameter)?

Comment: You don't have to re-create the panel, but the entire scene is repainted every time you call paintComponent().  The timing will have to be done from within the paintComponent() method.

Comment: Sounds like you have code. You need to post that code for others to tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033690/add-delay-of-1-second-between-each-arc-of-a-rainbow/43033861#43033861 for a suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and
[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: @James Sine `paintComponent` is protected, that's should be a pretty could hint that it should never be called directly

Comment: It isn't called directly.

Comment: @James It's not what you say, it how you say, based on your previous comment, it is inferred that you are suggesting that the OP should be calling `paintComponent` directly - If that's how I interrupted, it's a good chance that's how others will to

Comment: Now it won't be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

This is realitvely commong requirement and issue.  You should start by having a look at  [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for some basic information on how to solve the your basic problem.

You should also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more information about how painting works in Swing

The core design choices you want to focus on are:

1. Don't block the Event Dispatching Thread, this will prevent it from painting anything or responding to new events
2. Don't update the UI from outside the context of the EDT
3. Painting should paint state.  It should not be focused on making logical decisions where possible, instead, it should reliant on one or more models to provide it the information it needs to paint itself

---

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Shape> shapes;
        private int yPos = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            shapes = new ArrayList<>(25);

            Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    yPos += 10;
                    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(0, yPos, getWidth(), yPos);
                    shapes.add(line);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(2000);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Shape line : shapes) {
                g2d.draw(line);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```